# GNU-make check if element exists in list/array

Tags: arrays, list, element, gnu-make, exists

I have a list defined in the make file and the user is supposed to set an environment variable which I need to find in this list. Is there a way using gnu make to do this? I want to do this outside any recipe, before make starts building any targets. It is a QA check to make sure user sets the env. variable to a value within a range/list.

On terminal:

```
setenv ENV_PARAM x
```

In Makefile:

```
PARAMS := a b c

if ${ENV_PARAM} exists in $(PARAMS)
  true
else
  false
endif
```

@MadScientist's answer works. Is there a way to wrap the if block with a foreach loop to test multiple parameters?

```
KEYS    := PARAMS FACTORS
PARAMS  := a b c
FACTORS := x y z

foreach v in ($(KEYS)) {
  ifneq ($(filter $(ENV_$(v)),$(v)),)
    $(info $(ENV_$(v)) exists in $(v))
  else
    $(info $(ENV_$(v)) does not exist in $(v))
  endif
}
```

Comment: The example you give is not clear enough.  There are two different places in make such a test could be used: you might want to make that test in a recipe for a target, or you might want to make the test outside of any recipe, before make starts building targets.  They syntax for these two is very different so you need to provide more information about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function to do this:

```
PARAMS := a b c

ifneq ($(filter $(ENV_PARAM),$(PARAMS)),)
    $(info $(ENV_PARAM) exists in $(PARAMS))
else
    $(info $(ENV_PARAM) does not exist in $(PARAMS))
endif
```

Read: "if the result of searching for the ENV_PARAM value in PARAMS is not empty, run the 'true' block else run the 'false' block".

*UPDATE*

Your second question really cannot be answered fully with the information you've provided.  In order to know the best way to do it we need to know what you are really going to do inside the if-statement, when the condition is true and when it is false.  Are you going to declare more variables?  Create some rules?  Something else?  There are many ways to do what you want and the cleanest one may be different depending on what you want to do.

However, a general solution would involve using `define` to create the content of the loop, then using `foreach` and `eval`, something like this:

```
KEYS    := PARAMS FACTORS
PARAMS  := a b c
FACTORS := x y z

define LOOPBODY
  ifneq ($$(filter $$(ENV_$(v)),$(v)),)
    $$(info $$(ENV_$(v)) exists in $(v))
  else
    $$(info $$(ENV_$(v)) does not exist in $(v))
  endif
endef

$(foreach v,$(KEYS),$(eval $(LOOPBODY)))
```

You might be interested in a set of posts I made regarding metaprogramming in GNU make: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/

Comment: taking it a step further, is there a way to wrap this ifneq block inside a foreach block? I would like to have a test for multiple parameters. I did a lot of search but could not find any example which showed a similar usage. I have updated my question with what I want.

Comment: Do you mean, test whether any one of a number of parameters are present?  You can give multiple words to the first argument of `filter` and it will return any of them that match: `$(filter $(P1) $(P2) $(P3),$(PARAMS))`

Comment: I have many parameters and would like to have a foreach loop to iterate through this list instead of writing an ifneq block for each of them. In general as well, I have come across many cases when I would like to test some condition within a for loop, but could not find any pointers anywhere. Is that make's limitation?

Comment: This worked for me. I had tried everything except `eval`. One update though - the info statement needs two '$'s. I will go through your posts to understand 'make' better. Thanks a lot for taking time out to answer my questions.

Comment: Oops you're right I missed a few double-$ although those are the only ones that make a difference in this particular example.  Serves me right for typing without testing!